# Strings and Test-Path Issues

Tags: powershell, vmware, datastore, powercli

I am working on a PowerCLI (VMware) script that will copy the VMX from the datastores for each VM.  One of the initial issues was working with spaces in the VM name.  After fixing that issue, there was another hurdle that I'm still struggling on.  I am doing a Test-Path to check to make sure the datastore and folder where the VMX file resides can be reached before trying to copy the file.  However, the Test-Path fails with the following message:

Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''vmstore' does not exist.

The ultimate issue is the ' (single quote) just before vmstore being sent to the Test-Path cmdlet.  But the output of the variable containing the full path doesn't contain that additional quote.  Also when doing the Test-Path with the path entered in directly and using the single quotes, it works fine.

Here's the full script of getting the VMX file location and testing the path:

```
$gstrdatastorepath = "vmstore:\Cluster_Name\"

$lobjPrimaryDisk = Get-HardDisk -VM $VM | where {$_.name -EQ "Hard disk 1"} #looks for the first hard disk listed in VM definition. This is typically the primary source for the VMX file

$lstrDiskText = $lobjPrimaryDisk.filename #convert the filename to a string for manipulation.
#The string is typically as follows (without the quotes):  "[datastore_name] folder_name/filename.vmdk
#Only the datastore_name and the folder_name are needed.  The following now splits those from the vmdk file

$lstrDiskSplitInfo = $lstrDiskText.split("\/") #splits the text into two sections. First section is the primary information needed, the second is not used

#Now the datastore_name and the folder_name need to be split

$lstrDiskFolderSplitInfo = $lstrDiskSplitInfo[0] -split " ", 2 #splits the text into the datastore and folder name on the datastore. option 2 used in the event spaces are in VM name.

#Put the Disk and Folder information into separate variables

$lstrdatastorename = $lstrDiskFolderSplitInfo[0] -replace '[[\]]',''  #removes the square brackets from the datastore name


$lstrfoldername = $lstrDiskFolderSplitInfo[1] #gets the folder name from the previous split

$completeDataStorePath = $gstrdatastorepath + $lstrdatastorename + "\" + $lstrfoldername #combines the information to return the full path of the VMX file

$completeVMXPathQuoted = "`'$completeDataStorePath`'" #put the path in a single quote for VM's with spaces in the name
```

The value of $completeVMXPathQuoted is 'vmstore:\Cluster_Name\Data_Store\VM_Name' where VM_Name may or may not contain spaces.

When doing the Test-Path, using the $completeVMXPathQuoted variable, it fails with the message mentioned above.

But when doing Test-Path -Path 'vmstore:\Cluster_Name\Data_Store\VM_Name' it works fine.

What am I missing? Where is that second single quote mark coming from?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There is no `Test-Path` in the code you posted. Show the full code and the full error message.

Comment: do you get the same error using either of these? `[System.IO.File]::Exists('C:\file.txt')` or `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists('C:\directory\')`

Comment: Here's the test-path code and output:

    Test-Path -Path $completeVMXPathQuoted

Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''vmstore' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $completeVMXPathQuoted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ('vmstore:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Comment: Please edit your question. Code and error messages in comments tend to become unreadable.